# Can't get proper JSON response from face.com API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i'm working on sliverlight wrapper for wp7. This app is on https://github.com/slodge/face. As you see, this app works well, but I want to change one thing: Return JSON response together with mood attribute(which is absent). According to documentation, http://developers.face.com/docs/api/faces-detect/, it can be solved by specifying attributes=all in request url. After I changed it in code, [image]

Nothing happened. I suppose I made it in wrong way. What I have to do? Where I have to change url?

Comment: You're doing a POST - how are you setting your request body?

Comment: i suppose This forms request body according to parameters that are passed in method(dict). I'm not strong in web services and can't find place where exactly this request is set and send. Would be so kind run this app on your machine and change request url for me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (Added attributes param to the detect/recognize methods)

```
public FaceAPI faces_detect(List<string> urls, string filename, List<string> ownerIds, List<string> attributes, string callBackUrl)
{
    List<string> list = this.prep_lists(urls, ownerIds, attributes);
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dict.Add("urls", list[0]);
    dict.Add("owner_ids", list[1]);
    dict.Add("attributes", list[2]);
    dict.Add("_file", "@" + filename);
    dict.Add("callback_url", callBackUrl);

    return this.call_method("faces/detect", dict);
}
```

And call the detect method normally.

Lior
Face.com Team

Answer (score 0):

The string you are generating is garbage - not a valid param string, but something that looks like `param1=value1?param2=value2&param3=value3`

Instead of hacking these strings together, why not add your extra parameter to the `Dictionary<string,string> param` collection, and then let http_build_query do its job?

And if that doesn't help, then use a debugger to check what the strings generated actually look like....

And if that doesn't help, then use fiddler2 to check the HTTP communication....